# как смотреть данные исполнительного файла тгбота main.py в ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, aiogram, telegrambots

при запуске main.py во время нажатий на кнопки бота в консоль выводилась информация о пользователях,
файлы бота я закинул на хостинг beget и запустил его через файл(скрин), как я понял файл теперь запущен в фоновом режиме, как мне подключиться к нему, чтобы все данные, которые выводились все это время, не потерялись и я мог посмотреть, что выводилось в консоль
[файл](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U2MY.png)

процесс файла я могу видеть, но не понимаю как заглянуть "внутрь", помогите пожалуйста, очень нужно.
[скрин](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG3h0.png)

Comment: Удалите скриншот `anon.service` и вставьте файл в тело вопроса как код.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартный вывод для systemd сервисов перенаправляется в журнал. Посмотреть записи журнала для вашего сервиса

```bash
journalctl -u anon.service
```

Если permission denied, то выполните команду под sudo

Comment: спасибо огромное, очень помогли